# Run if on multiple conditions, no error, but data doesn't change

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I tried to impute missing data with median on conditions, no error but the data didn't change. Why and how can I make it work?

```
housing = read.csv('housingsample22.csv')
if (housing$Car == 0 && housing$Tunit == 1) {
    housing$Car = median(housing$Car)
}
if (housing$Landsize == 0 && housing$Tunit != 1) { 
   housing$Landsize = median(housing$Landsize)
}
if (housing$BuildingArea == 0 && housing$TTHouse == 1) {
    housing$BuildingArea = median(housing$BuildingArea[housing$TTHouse == 1])
}
```

Comment: You should use something like `housing$Car[housing$Car == 0 & housing$Tunit == 1] <- median(housing$Car)`. Please note the difference between `&` and `&&`.

Comment: Did you by chance get any warnings in this code? Perhaps `Warning...: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`? The only way you won't get that warning is if your frame `housing` has only one row. To add to @nicola's comment, nothing changed because the equality tests did not match for the first row only (therefore the first of each vector comparison). Pro tip: I do ignore some types of warnings, but only when I expect them, otherwise they usually indicate an assumption of the data (or the code) is incorrect.

Comment: @r2evans Actually, I got a warning using &.. no error for &&. I am confused about the difference between & and &&, I'll go search for some material and figure it out later. Thanks!

Comment: @nicola I'll this later, found a solve that worked so far. Thanks!

Comment: user12190109, you're right (my bad), the `&&` doesn't warn you, because `&&` only returns a single `logical`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason your data doesn't change. Take the first condition for example:

```
if (housing$Car == 0 && housing$Tunit == 1) 
   {housing$Car = median(housing$Car)}
```

You are checking if an entire column is equal to zero. It will most definitely take only the first element to evaluate the condition.

What you could do it something like:

```
require(dplyr)
median_car = median(housing$Car)

housing = housing %>% 
  mutate(Car = if_else(Car == 0 & Tunit == 1,median_car,Car))
```

You can write the other 3 statements similarly together.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: Please include any external package you are using. This solution doesn't work in base R.

Comment: Included the package (dplyr).

Comment: I remember I got that error when I was using &, but no warning for &&. Yes, your code worked. Thanks a lot.